# DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED by Google Ads API for PHP

Tags: php, laravel, google-ads-api

I want to use the Google Ads API to access Google Ads reports.
As a preliminary step, we want to use the GoogleCustomerServiceClient to retrieve customer information.

```
$MMC_ID = <My MMC 10 digits number>;

$credentialsIniPath = app_path('resources/credentials/google/google_ads_php.ini');

$oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
    ->fromFile($credentialsIniPath)
    ->build();

$googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
    ->fromFile($credentialsIniPath)
    ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
    ->build();

$customerServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getCustomerServiceClient();

try {
    $customer = $customerServiceClient->getCustomer(ResourceNames::forCustomer($MMC_ID));
} catch(GoogleAdsException $e) {
    $this->error($e->getMessage());
}
```

But it returns an error

```
Fault
-------
Status code: 7
Details: The caller does not have permission
Failure: {"errors":[{"errorCode":{"authorizationError":"DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED"},"message":"The developer token is not approved. Non-approved developer tokens can only be used with test accounts."}]}
```

The account Oauth2 login that created MMC, MMC is a test account.
In `google_ads_php.ini`, clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken, and developerToken are already filled in.
The `refreshToken` has just been generated.

What should I check for in this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new one from this URL and it's for testing.
https://adwords.google.com/um/Welcome/?sf=mt

Resolved.